# Inferior Python mode seems to redirect some output back as input. How to fix?

Tags: python, repl

I'm running a Python3 REPL in `Inferior Python Mode`.

When user input follows directly after some output, the next output seems to be redirected to the REPL, interpreted as user input, and evaluated. See the example below:

```
>>> three = '3'
>>> input()  # as expected
three
'three'
>>> input('enter something: ')  # very strange
enter something: three
'3'
>>>
```

This only happens when I run the REPL in Emacs, not when I run it in a "regular" terminal outside Emacs.

What's going on?

Comment: I can not reproduce the behavior here (on Emacs version 28.2 or 30). Do you see this behavior when starting from `emacs -q`? Which Emacs version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I should have checked this right away. Will do once I get around to it.